# Bootstrap modal doesn't popup in razor pages

Tags: bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I have copied and pasted following code into my razor page view. After i click on the button nothing happening. Whats wrong with it?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#exampleModalCenter">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added these two links into my _Layout  but still anything popups up

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included all the necessary bootstrap files in _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: which files?????

Comment: `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: added two links but still doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes apply to Bootstrap 4 and earlier. You are using Bootstrap 5.2.2.

Per the [Bootstrap 5.2 modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#live-demo), `data-target` should be `data-bs-target` and `data-toggle` should be `data-bs-toggle`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```